# How to install PGBouncer 1.7.2 on Solaris 10

Tags: openssl, gnu-make, libevent, pgbouncer

I am attempting to upgrade my PGbouncer from 1.5.4 to 1.7.2 but no luck. It's returning error:

```
# gmake
     CC       lib/usual/tls/tls.c
lib/usual/tls/tls.c: In function `tls_info_callback':
lib/usual/tls/tls.c:295: error: structure has no member named `ecdh'
lib/usual/tls/tls.c:296: warning: implicit declaration of function `EC_GROUP_get_curve_name'
lib/usual/tls/tls.c:296: warning: implicit declaration of function `EC_KEY_get0_group'
lib/usual/tls/tls.c:296: error: structure has no member named `ecdh'
gmake: *** [.objs/pgbouncer/lib/usual/tls/tls.o] Error 1
```

I have dependencies needed with the following version:

```
GNU Make 3.82
Libevent 2.1.8
OpenSSL 1.0.1t
```

OS Version:

```
Solaris 10 1/13 s10x_u11wos_24a X86
```

Does anyone encounter this error? Or anyone successfully installed it on Solaris with version 1.7.2?

Appreciate any advice and recommendation.

Comment: It sounds like you are using are old version of OpenSSL, like 1.0.0 or 0.9.8. I don't know what Solaris 10 provides, but it sounds a lot like some errors experienced on OS X with Apple's ancient 0.9.8. Can you verify you are using the OpenSSL you expect to use?

Comment: Let me check. But yeah, seems it's using different OpenSSL libraries. I let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @jww I tried to re-compile OpenSSL version OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017  from source and install it on different PATH: /opt/local/openssl. Then I used that path for pgbouncer compilation but it's still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using TLS with pgbouncer?  If not, you can pass `--without-openssl` to the `./configure` script and build without it.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response. I need to compile and use TLS. Thanks